# MYSQL find if similar entry exists in two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, wordpress

I have 2 tables in a database: `images_1` and `wp_posts`, in them one of the entries is image file name, while the other has similar name for the post title, it's just that in wordpress database that entry has image file type attached to it. Since I'm making import from `table_1`, I need to check if that post already exists in `wp_post` table before I import it.

So my `table_1` has structure kinda like this:

**table_1**

```
filename_uploaded
-----------------
asd654as8_dasd3
a32asd586as_d6584
asdad_asdlf
```

While my `wp_post` table has, for `post_type = attachment`

**wp_post**

```
post_title
----------
asd654as8_dasd3.jpg
a32asd586as_d6584.jpg
asdad_asdlf.png
```

So I tried with:

```
$img_query = "SELECT *
              FROM table_1
              WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM wp_posts
                                WHERE wp_posts.post_title LIKE table_1.filename_uploaded
                                AND wp_posts.post_type = 'attachment')";

$img_query_query = $wpdb->get_results($img_query, ARRAY_A);
```

Which doesn't work.

The thing is that I cannot check if they are equal, because they are not. They are similar, but the `post_title` has file type extension. I searched about using [regular expressions in mysql queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html), but I'm not sure how to do it.

Any help will do.

EDIT:

I just notice I get

> [Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'like']

My `table_1` is in swedish_ci and `wp_post` is in general_ci.

I tried adding `COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci` at the end, but no luck.

Following Gordon Linoff's advice I tried

```
"SELECT t_img.*
          FROM img_images t_img
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM wp_posts p
                            WHERE p.post_title LIKE CONCAT(t_img.filename_uploaded, '.%')
                            AND p.post_type = 'attachment') COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci";
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close but not taking the suffix into account.  So:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM wp_posts p
                  WHERE p.post_title LIKE CONCAT(t1.filename_uploaded, '.%') AND
                        p.post_type = 'attachment'
                 );
```

Comment: I noticed I have different collations in my tables, any fix for that as well?

Comment: See @PratikBhalodiya answer for why a LIKE can be a little inaccurate

Comment: I manually changed collation of both tables to same (`utf8_general_ci`), and this returned about the amount I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use this query and don't use like query it's give problem when some user name like this `pratik` , `pratik12` you will execute `pratik` and like give you both records

```
select * 
from table_1 
  left join wp_post on wp_post.post_title = CONCAT(table_1.filename_uploaded,'.jpg') 
where wp_post.post_title = null
```

Comment: I agree with not using LIKE, but what if someone uploaded a `.png` or a `.gif` or ......

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the extension that's being added, try with:

```
...    
WHERE wp_posts.post_title LIKE table_1.filename_uploaded + '%'
...
```

SQL Like operator: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: See @PratikBhalodiya answer for why a LIKE can be a little inaccurate

Answer (score 0):

There are a multitude of string functions in MYSQL [See the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html)

Using those you could do this

```
$img_query = "SELECT *
              FROM table_1 t1
              WHERE NOT EXISTS 
                 (SELECT *
                  FROM wp_posts
                  WHERE wp_posts.post_title = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.filename_upload, '.', 1)
                    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'attachment')";
```

This will also cope with any file extensions so if you have `.jpg` and `.png` and `.gif` etc image formats uploaded you are covered.